# How to extract metadata for more than 20000 videos from channel using YouTube Data API v3?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to use Youtube Data API v3 to extract video metadata (especially title and publish date) for all videos in a channel. Currently, I'm only being able to extract details the last 20000 videos using the `playlistItems()` endpoint. Is there a way to extract metadata for more than 20000 videos from a single channel?

Here's the python code I'm using to extract metadata for 20000 videos.

```
youtube = build('youtube','v3',developerKey= "YOUTUBE_API_KEY")
channelId = "CHANNEL_ID"

# getting all video details
contentdata = youtube.channels().list(id=channelId,part='contentDetails').execute()
playlist_id = contentdata['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads']
videos = [ ]
next_page_token = None

while 1:
    res = youtube.playlistItems().list(playlistId=playlist_id,part='snippet',maxResults=50,pageToken=next_page_token).execute()
    videos += res['items']
    next_page_token = res.get('nextPageToken')
    if next_page_token is None:
        break

# getting video id for each video
video_ids = list(map(lambda x:x['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'], videos))
```

The solution to this problem can either be forcing the API to extract metadata more than 20000 videos from a channel or specifying a time period during which video was uploaded. That way, the code can be run again and again for multiple time periods to extract metadata for all videos.

Comment: What is your question, please?

Comment: Apologies for making it confusing. I want to either extract metadata for more than 20000 videos from a channel or extract metadata for 20000 videos from a channel for a specified time period. Either of these will be a solution.

Comment: OK; then please edit your post above accordingly.

Comment: Done. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I don’t see anything in the code that causes this 20k items limit.  Can you please explain from where you determine some limit?  Is it because of a limited number of pages available due to quota?

Comment: @Dennis It's a limit imposed by the Youtube Data API. It's very hard to find any documentation about it but you'll find similar issues posted by other users. https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/40866109.html

Comment: [I finally answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78187760).

Answer (score -1):

So the work around lies in smartly breaking down the channel into either **small time ranges** or **multiple playlists** or on some other parameter.

Here is an example of how you can break the entire channel's videos into time ranges based in publishing time.

```
res = youtube.playlistItems().list(
    playlistId=playlist_id,
    part='snippet',
    maxResults=50,
    publishedAfter='2022-01-01T00:00:00Z',  # Set your desired start date
    publishedBefore='2022-12-31T23:59:59Z',  # Set your desired end date
    pageToken=next_page_token
).execute()
```

you can keep looping by changing the time range till you  get all the videos.

I hope this solves your issue, please let me know your feedback and keep coding!!!!

Comment: `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore` are not [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint parameters. You are probably confusing with [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint but note that the latter is known to be bugged.

Comment: [I tested this method properly](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/255#issuecomment-2004348439) assuming that the first returned page of results is correct and for a 260K videos channel, I only got about 60K videos, so I confirm the feeling I had in my previous comment.